# How can I gather the output of a while loop in a single pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a script composed of a while loop with an echo in it:

```
while my_condition
do
echo [my_output]
done
```

How can I gather the output in a single pipe?

I would need to use `column` after the output pipe'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No need to "transform" anything, just put the pipe after the loop:

```
while my_condition
do
    echo [my_output]
done | column
```

For example:

```
$ while read num; do 
    echo "$num" 
  done < <(seq 1 100) | column
1   11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81  91
2   12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82  92
3   13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83  93
4   14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84  94
5   15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85  95
6   16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86  96
7   17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87  97
8   18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88  98
9   19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89  99
10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Comment: You could even use a pipe to “feed” the output of `seq` to the loop. No need for FIFO redirection.